# Change the default database in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

When I open SQL Server Management Studio, I have many databases listed there, If I open a database and open the list of its tables and right click on a table and say `Select Top 1000 rows` it correctly queries that table of that database BUT it also automatically picks `TempDb` as the database in the available database combobox in the toolbar  like the picture below.

[image]

So now if I want to write a query by clicking on "New Query" it will look at "tempDB", which is annoying. Is there a way to change this behavior ?

Comment: Your user account determines the default database.

Comment: If you right click on the database server in the object explorer and choose 'New Query' it will open a new query window attached to whichever database you selected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can select a default database per connection in SQL Server, which might help. Once you've set it, each time you connect to that server, the default database will be selected.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Pretty much the same as my comment (ish) but also suffers from the same problem that it won't help if you select a different database than the one you have connected to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that DavidG's comment is the best answer.
"Your user account determines the default database."

You can choose default database for your user account in the user properties.

Security - Logins - right mouse click - Properties - and select the default DataBase.
And so, every time when you open new or existed query window the current DataBase would be selected from the default dataBase setting in user porperties.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33311690)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue using SSMS 19.3 when connecting to a Sql Server 2016 instance. I tried to set the "Connect to database:" value in the "Connection Properties" tab of the "Connect to Database Engine" connection popup but it didn't work for me.

The solution I found was to specify the default database in the "Additional Connection Parameter" tab in the "Connect to Database Engine" popup.

Here's how to do it:

In Sql Server Management Studio, open the "Connect to Database Engine" popup. There's multiple ways to do this. An easy one is to open a new query window and click on the "Change connection" icon in the top left area

[image]

Which brings up the "Connect to Database Engine" popup. Click on the "Options >>" button in the bottom right hand corner

[image]

Which displays the different configuration tabs for the connection. Click on the "Additional Connection Parameters" tab in the upper right hand corner

[image]

Then just enter this into the text box that is displayed (substitute the database name you want to set as the default in place of `YourDatabaseName`)
and then click the "Connect" button on the bottom left hand side of the popup

[image]

This should then set the default database for this connection to the database you want.

Hope this helps!